# Как правильно использовать несколько секторов памяти?

Tags: c, компоновщик, stm32

Сам вопрос возник по причине того, что моя программа для микроконтроллера `stm32f429ZITx` вылетает в `HardFault_Handler` просто при добавлении нескольких дополнительных переменных, при этом не со старта, а течении работы,  при вызове функций `emwin` и `freeRTOS`.

С памятью дело обстоит так:

Стандартная `RAM` память микроконтроллера(адрес `0x20000000`)

`CCMRAM` память микроконтроллера(адрес `0x10000000`)

И `SDRAM`, подключенная через `FMC` и находящаяся в едином адресном пространстве с остальной памятью, которую я использую для управления дисплеем через LTDC. Но `SDRAM` значительно больше, чем необходимо дисплею.(`0xD0000000`)

За границы основной памяти я вышел давно и прописал линкеру использовать CCMRAM.
Прописывал в `scatter` файле `keil` 5 вот так

```
LR_IROM1 0x08000000 0x00200000  {    ; load region size_region
  ER_IROM1 0x08000000 0x00200000  {  ; load address = execution address
   *.o (RESET, +First)
   *(InRoot$$Sections)
   .ANY (+RO)
  }
  RW_IRAM1 0x20000000 0x00030000  {  ; RW data
   .ANY (+RW +ZI)
  }
  RW_IRAM2 0x10000000 0x00010000  {
   .ANY (+RW +ZI)
  }
}
```

Думаю, что проблема возникает на стыке использования основной `RAM` и `CCMRAM`.
Например куча/стек начинается в `RAM` памяти и заканчивается в `CCMRAM` и если код инкриментирует указатель(скажем `emWin` или `freeRTOS`), то указатель может попасть в область, выходящую за границы `ram` памяти.(хотя, если память распределяется в подряд, такими функциями как `malloc`, то такое может произойти в лёгкую.)

Подскажите, как правильно настраивать память в таких ситуациях?

P.S. Я подозреваю, что надо будет будет вручную прописывать, где какие переменные располагать и ограничить стек какой-нибудь одной памятью.

Comment: Вопрос непростой. При старте программы вам доступна только RAM-память. Тут вы можете настроить тактовые сигналы и инициализировать FMC. Но после этого что вам мешает использовать только SDRAM? Например, первичную настройку делать в отдельном с-файле, а линкеру указать, чтобы данные соответствующего объектного файла помещались в RAM, а всё остальное - в SDRAM.

Comment: Немного офтопика, а Zephyr RTOS портирован уже под это семейство контроллеров?